# Aptana 3 does not creates new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana3

When I try to create new rails project Aptana gves :

"Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails direct
ory first."

error and also when I type ls it does not give current project folder content it gives something else. In addition when I open the Webrick for the ptoject it does not show my project instead it gives rails initial front page.

Do you see the error please help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Aptana in windows, and your workspace is C:\user\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace. The problem is that the folder of your workspace is read-only. You should change the privileges in this folder for you can write into the folder of yours project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Aptana Studio. I got a similar message after my manipulations with DevKit_mingw assembly, although before Aptana it works fine. In my case uninstalling Ruby, devKit and Aptana helped. Then I just install [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) + AptanaStudio. I hope my experience will help someone else.